# Why does my shader's Texture become unselected when I run my game?

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, materials, lines

I'd like to add a custom material to a line that I'm drawing in Unity (using [Vectrosity](https://starscenesoftware.com/vectrosity.html)).  I'm using Unity's built-in "Unlit/Texture" shader.  When I drag a texture from my Resources directory into the "Texture" slot in my shader, everything looks good:

[image: Unity editor with texture selected]

But when I click play, the texture disappears:

[image: Unity editor with texture unselected]

and my line doesn't show up in my game.  However, if I drag the texture to the shader's texture slot *after* I click play, the texture seems to "stick" and my line renders as expected:

[image: Line with texture applied]

But once I stop and start the game, the texture again disappears.

Why is Unity kicking out my texture when my game starts?  Is there something wrong with my texture?  I don't see any warnings or errors in the console.  I've tried with numerous different textures, and they all do the same thing.

I'm using Unity 5.6.1f1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some script is removing the texture from the material at runtime.

I suggest you check `Awake`, `OnEnable` and `Start` on your scripts, apart from an odd Unity bug, the culprit should be there somewhere.

You should search for a `Material` type variable, and then look if there's a `materialVariableName.mainTexture = someValue;`. When `someValue` is `null`, the material's texture is obviously reset.

Edit: I forgot, you should check for `materialVariableName.SetTexture("_MainTex", someValue);` too.

Comment: Thanks, I think this was it.  I changed how I was initializing my Vectrosity line, and now my material doesn't lose its texture on play.